# Co-Simulation PSpice - Matlab

Tags: simulation, matlab, pspice, simulink

I simulated in Orcad an inverter, and I wanted that to Co-Simulate it in Matlab. The problem is that I get only '0' value on Simulink scope. The circuit in Orcad is (see first picture.) and the circuit in Simulink and the settings for it (see second picture.). Last picture is the result of simulation. The quiestion is: why my Output is always on 0 , I tought that the scope can't get the digital signals and I tried to get the values of variables on Matlab and plot them, but same result.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You may have more luck asking in their forums, though I'm not dismissing the possibility that someone may know.

Comment: I did that, but still no answer.

Comment: Do you need this interaction because you plan on using a more complicated circuit that can't be modelled in Matlab, or do you only need the results of the simulation for processing in Matlab? If it's the former, it's a valid question, but if it's the latter, PSpice should have an export data somewhere, that lets you export the results of the simulation. Or are you just testing this? If you think to test a "real model", you should know that these are, at best, approximations, so an inverter would simply be `not(x)` in Matlab, or similar.

Comment: I need to solve this simple circuit because I have to deal with something similar in a more complex circuit that use logical gates. I saw that only when logic gates are used I can't get the right output on Scope, but if I simulate a simple voltage divider the output signal is properly showed on Scope.

Comment: Well, FWIW, I see you already have a source in the PSpice schematic, yet you also added a constant input in Simulink -- these may clash. Also, IIRC, PSpice uses something similar to `$PWR` for nodes (i.e.  global power supply node)? I'm not sure, but maybe you need to take care of supplies, too.

Comment: The supply in Orcad, it is necessary to be able to set at ' Input Sources '  window in Simulink the source that I want to change its value, BUT i really can't understand why i can't reach the digital signals only, because if I use any others components it  works.